# How to create different layout for different orientation in android?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, orientation, content-assist

I would like to have different activity.xml files for different orientations.
I have created a another folder with name `layout-land`. When I copy and paste the activity_main.xml file into it, then screen size is automatically getting oriented to landscape.

But after doing this, code assist is not working. Its showing the following error when I press `ctrl+s`

`Content assist not available at the current location`

what is the reason for this? Did I do anything wrong for creating different layouts for both orientation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like an IDE-specific issue more than anything. The way you're doing it is correct. Assuming you a layout with the same name in as the other inside of layout-land, you should be good to go. Just give it a whirl.

Comment: Ya. Application is running fine. But, I am not getting code assistance  only for these xml files.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an Eclipse error to me (Googling "Content assist not available at the current location gives me a lot of hits); try running your application on a device and it will most likely work. It doesn't sound like you've done anything wrong.